# Sinch integration with chat bot platform

Tags: sinch

is it possible to use chat bot on platforms like Dialogflow, IBM Watson, Kore.ai etc in integration with CAAS platforms like Sinch? To elaborate my query, I want to use Sinch for making calls to user and use my chatbot to provide dialogue responses to the user instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer your query on behalf of Kore.ai & as well can give you insights regarding Watson & DialogFlow

Kore.ai- currently has a very vast library of API integrations available for most of the IVR services available in the market. Kore.ai also has an inbuilt ASR engine & the best TTS feature. This will help the incoming voice to be converted to text & the response can be automated based on the learning you impart to the bot. - I tried a similar one like this for personal use.

In perspective of IBM & Dialogflow - there are some of the integrations missing , since they do not actively collaborate with all vendors in the market (due to their size & presence) - and also, they have their own internal softwares which they'd ideally want to push for public use.

The TTS is IBM Watson & DialogFlow is not state-of the art there are many missing elements in how the voice is intepreted to text.  Just the other day I was trying to compare the ASR of DialogFlow & Kore.ai - and I had visible differences. I will soon blog with the transcripts I received from both platforms.

To my view I'd suggest trying out Kore.ai platform & then comparing the same with others.

Answer (score 0):

The chatbot platforms you have cited, Dialogflow an Watson for sure, have an extensive API and various methods to accept incoming messages, elaborate them, create discussion, create responses and send them back to the exterior. 
So it is possible in principle to integrate them with the external world, but you need to study the inners of the framework and how it dialogates with external sources.

The principle with these chatbot frameworks, that often integrate also Natural Language Undersanding(NLU) and NLP capabilites, is like this:

- text input from external world -> understand text\extract entities(names,addresses,ecc...) -> choose appopriate response/create a discussion/create a question -> send the response back to world